# how to embed widgets to images and save it to the device

Tags: flutter

I have an image with a `container` on it. I want to be able to edit the `TextField` inside the container and save the image as an image to the device.

My current setup is a `stack` where I have the image and a container on top of each other. How can I save that as an image?

Note that I don't want to save the whole screen, just the image and whatever on it.

```
Future<File> createWave(BuildContext context, GlobalKey screen) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = screen.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    File imgFile = File('$directory/screenshot.png');
    await imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
    return imgFile;
  }
```

[image: the stup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully since flutter uses skia to render it's graphics, we are able to take screenshots of widgets and there is already a really good [article](https://medium.com/@agungsurya/take-a-screenshot-of-a-certain-widget-in-flutter-ad263edc4e55) that does somethings similar. Basically you wrap your widget in a RepaintBoundary and assign it a key then use the key to call the RenderObject.toImage method. Here is another [simple example](https://codesearchonline.com/index.php/flutter-screenshot/) to do this. It's amazing how simple it is :D